# Implicit function theorem real analysis homework problem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(\rho, \phi, \theta) = (\rho \sin\phi\sin\theta, \rho\cos\phi)$.

a) Use the implicit function theorem to show that the equation $f(\rho, \phi, \theta) = (1, 1)$ can be solved for $(\phi, \theta)$ as a function of $\rho$ near the point $(\sqrt{3})\arctan\sqrt{2}, \pi/4).$

b) Use the implicit function theorem to find $\phi'(\sqrt{3})$ and $\theta'(\sqrt{3})$

c) Give a geometric description of the situation and explain why the results are reasonable

I'm lost, help me please. In part (a), why is the implicit function theorem needed just to solve for $(\phi, \theta)$ as a function of $\rho$ near a point? Could you explain that and show how it's done?

Comment: You're not actually solving for $\phi,\theta$; you're using the implicit function theorem to show that it's possible to do so.  The implicit function theorem states that it's possible to solve a system of equations for two variables when...?

Comment: I presume the point should be $(\sqrt{3},...)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify notation, let $f(\rho, \alpha) = \rho(\sin \alpha_1 \sin \alpha_2, \cos \alpha_1)^T$. Then ${\partial f(\rho, \alpha) \over \partial \alpha} = \rho 
\begin{bmatrix} \cos \alpha_1 \sin \alpha_2 & \sin \alpha_1 \cos \alpha_2 \\ -\sin \alpha_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$,
and $\det {\partial f(\rho, \alpha) \over \partial \alpha} = \rho^2 (\sin \alpha_1)^2 \cos \alpha_2$.

We are given the point $(\hat{\rho}, \hat{\alpha}) = (\sqrt{3}, \arctan \sqrt{2}, {\pi \over 4})^T$, from which we get $f(\hat{\rho}, \hat{\alpha}) = (1,1)^T$ and $\det {\partial f(\hat{\rho}, \hat{\alpha}) \over \partial \alpha} = \sqrt{2} \neq 0$.

The implicit function theorem allows us to write $\alpha$ locally as a function of $\rho$  (let us write $\beta(\rho)$) in a neighbourhood of $\hat{\rho}=\sqrt{3}$, and in this neighborhood, we have $f(\rho, \beta(\rho)) = (1,1)^T$.

Furthermore, we have ${\partial \beta(\hat{\rho}) \over \partial \rho} = - ({\partial f(\hat{\rho}, \hat{\alpha}) \over \partial \alpha})^{-1} {\partial f(\hat{\rho}, \hat{\alpha}) \over \partial \rho} = -
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -{1 \over \sqrt{2}} \\ 1 & {1\over 2}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} {1 \over {\sqrt{3}}} \\{1 \over {\sqrt{3}}}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} {1 \over {\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}}} \\-{ {\sqrt{3}} \over 2}
\end{bmatrix}$ , from which we can read off the values of 
$\phi'(\sqrt{3})$, $\theta'(\sqrt{3})$ (assuming I have not made a computational error).

Comment: you are beautiful

Comment: Your comment has improved what has been a truly lousy day! Thank you!